# Qt5 project in MSVC 2010, need multi-byte character set but changing the project's character set doesn't work

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, qt, unicode, multibyte

I'm in the process of doing my first steps with Qt in MSVC. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Qt 5.3.

Everything works fine, but now I have legacy C-code which I have to include in my project. This c-code is using 8-bit characters for loading DLLs and stuff, so to make it work in MSVC, I have to change the project's character set from Unicode to Multibyte. This is working fine with normal C++ applications.

But when I'm now creating a Qt application and use this legacy code, the project seems to use Unicode, despite that fact that I've enabled the Multibyte character set in the Qt application's properties. So I get the following error for example:

error C2664: 'GetModuleFileNameW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'

The Qt application seems to ignore my Multibyte character setting in the project's properties and still uses Unicode. How can I change this?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your qt installation mkspecs directory and change the qmake.conf file of the platform you are using.

Change
Defines += UNICODE 
To
Defines += _MBCS

Answer (score 0):

In your .pro file, put the lines

```
DEFINES -= UNICODE
DEFINES += _MBCS
```